# roscore not launching due to weird Computer Name

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ROS Indigo (not built from source). Everything seems to have installed perfectly and the first 4 tutorials work well too. However, when I launch roscore, it doesn't launch, and it shows the following error.

Unable to contact my own server at [http://1103:33101/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

```
ping 1103
```

For more tips, please see

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
```

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I've sort of found what the problem is after some speculation.

**My computer name is 1103 and user name is desktop (desktop@1103). So, when roscore tries to resolve the hostname "1103", it ends up resolving it to 0.0.4.79** (Verified this on some other hostname resolvers as well!).

Also, here's what "roswtf" outputs:
Local network configuration is invalid: Local hostname [1103] resolves to [0.0.4.79], which does not appear to be a local IP address ['127.0.0.1', '172.18.4.40'].

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198001/roscore-not-launching-due-to-weird-computer-name/) by [krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20901/krishna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't really a ROS problem at all. The underlying library for resolving your hostname to an IP address isn't giving the results you expect, because you've chosen a number as your hostname.

[RFC952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952) specifies that hostnames cannot begin with a number, but [RFC1123](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123) specifies that hostnames may be entirely numeric. This has caused [some contention](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=65041) in the Debian community.

The bottom line is that you should choose a hostname that is not entirely numeric.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20901/krishna/) on 2014-11-23**:
Thank you for the reply. This seems to be a guideline I can live with. I've found another workaround to the problem by setting the environment variable ROS_IP to 127.0.0.1.